# My prompt dialog displays with no background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a simple prompt. When I run it in jfiddle, it works perfectly fine -- but hosted on my own computer/site, it doesn't work at all. I must be missing something simple. Please have a look:

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('audio').mouseenter(function() {
    //  $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    //});
    function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element){
        var btns = {};
        btns[button1] = function(){ 
            $(this).dialog("close");
        };
        btns[button2] = function(){ 
            $('.level2').hide();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        };
        $("<div id='box'>Are you a <u>level 1</u>, or a <u>level 2</u> agent?</div>").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: "",
            modal:true,
            buttons:btns
        });
    }

    yesnodialog('Level 2', 'Level 1', $('.level2'));
```

Here it is running in jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CdwB9/421/
It looks totally fine to me

but, on my own site, it looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gV3mQHr.png]

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: Please verify (or post) the CSS used in your site. It can be causing this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is clearly not related to the javascript. It get's loaded correctly and the jQuery-ui magic with the markup, buttons and functionality etc is applied.

The reason for this bug has to be that you are either:

1. Not loading the jQuery-ui theme css-file. Check that this gets loaded. If you downloaded jQuery-ui from the official site, it should be in the .zip folder.
2. You are overwriting the jQuery-ui CSS with your own. This is less likely as the jQuery-ui markup has pretty unique class-names and a rather complex styling (meaning you would have MUCH CSS to be able to overwrite all of it).

I am 99 % sure it is the first suggestion, but you should check them both out.

The easiest way to check this is using Firefox and Firebug (or the built-in developertool in Chrome/Safari/Opera) and inspect the popup-element to see if any styles are applied to the markup.

PS: Welcome to SO :)